# VS code pytest finding test directory but not files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I'm trying to setup pytest for VS code. My project structure is the following.

```
root-
    |-projectA
      |-__init__.py
      |-tests
        |-__init__.py
        |-test_A1.py
        |-test_A2.py
    |-projectB
```

I can run pytest from the terminal:

```
cd root
pytest */tests
...
========================== 15 passed, 1 warning in 8.97s===========================================
```

These are my settings in VS code:

```
"python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "*/tests"
],
"python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
"python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
"python.testing.cwd": "root",
"python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
```

In VS code, it looks as if the test directory is found, but not the test files inside. If I click to run the test, nothing happens.

[image: VS code pytest snapshot]

Comment: please provide a [mre] including the test file contents.

Answer (score 0):

There exists [a possible solution](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8184#issuecomment-545684440) in github.

> Please could you uninstall the extension, then delete the folder
> ms-python.python-pythonVersion. Next reload VS Code and reinstall the
> latest version of the extension.

According to the answer, you can uninstall the Python extension.

Then delete the file that contains the extension from your `~/.vscode` folder such as `C:\Users\Administrator\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.9.11461009`.

Finally, reinstall Python extension then reload VSCode.